# Rebinding modifiers without xmodmap

Tags: linux, emacs, keyboard, xorg

In i3wm, I’m currently binding my left ‘win’ key to ‘ctrl’ via xmodmap with the following:

```
remove mod4 = Super_L
add control = Super_L
```

This works everywhere except in Emacs, which instead interprets pressing the left ‘win’ key as pressing ‘win’ and ‘ctrl’ at the same time.

An Emacs maintainer said my xmodmap is a misconfiguration and that I need to find another way to do the rebinding. I’ve looked into setxkbmap, but I couldn’t figure out how to do this particular reassignment. Does anyone know how to do it?

Alternatively, if there's a workaround in Emacs I could use that would achieve the same effect, that would help too!

Comment: I think you must additionally set the keycode of the win-key to control_[l|r], e.g.  `keycode 105 = Control_R; add control = Control_R`; check xev output for the correct keycode